# How to load data from mysql (php) before a jquery mobile page is shown perfectly like a native app and without crashes?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I am building an app and I use these technologies: cordova, jquery mobile, Intel-XDK (Build: Crosswalk), Ajax and Server Sent Events.
On the XDK-Emulator everything works fine but on the device it takes too long to load data from mysql (php) before jquery mobile page is shown and sometimes the app crashes.

```js
var $home = {
  
  load : function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxxxxx.php",
        type: 'POST',
  //dataType: "jsonp",
  //crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
        $showLoader.searching();
        },
        complete: function(){
        $showLoader.loadHidden();
        },
        async:true,
       
        data: {xxxxx : xxxxxxxx},
  
        sucess:function(r){
        $('#xxx').html(r);
        }
        
      });
    }
}

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#home",function(){
 $home.load();
});
```

**My Questions:**
Should I load all of these data into the local indexedDB first then work with them?
How is your architecture design? How did you handle this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, I Will Tell You Easy Method And If You Load data From The
>   Server The Use JSon Not Ajax. And Still you facing some problem then
>   Message Me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
                      {
                        var categoriesImgId = [];
                        var categoriesImg = [];

                        var getCategoriesId = localStorage.getItem('categoryIds');
                        $.getJSON("http://XYZ.php", function(data) {
                          $.each(data.YOUR ARRAYNAME, function(index, item) {

                            categoriesImgId.push(item.image_id);
                            categoriesImg.push(item.thumbimagepath);
                          }
                                );

                          for (i = 0; i < categoriesImgId.length; i++) {
                            var catListImgDiv = document.createElement('div');
                            catListImgDiv.setAttribute('id', "catListImgDiv" + i);
                            catListImgDiv.setAttribute('class', "pro_box");
                            catListImgDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'getCatImgIdFunc(' + categoriesImgId[i] + ');');
                            $('#CatListImgDiv').append(catListImgDiv);

                            var categoryListImage = document.createElement('img');
                            categoryListImage.setAttribute('id', "categoryListImage" + i);
                            categoryListImage.src = "" + categoriesImg[i];
                            $('#catListImgDiv' + i).append(categoryListImage);
                          }
                        }
                                 );

                      }
                     );
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi, but [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) says that: **This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to ajax**. I need to send some data first, for checking if the user is registered or not. Please, look at my questions, thanks for your answer.

Comment: hello , so you need to post data ..? and you want Complete Ajax format ..?

Comment: Yes and the data should be there before the page is shown like in a native app. The emulator works fine but the device doesn't. It takes too long and craches. If the data are stored in the localStorage, the app works faster. My idea is to create a indexeddb-database in a Webworker so the data could be sent via ServerSentEvents and stored in that indexeddb-database. Maybe the app could be more faster than now. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var finalGet = '';
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        finalGet = document.getElementById('inputUserStatus').value;

          $('#userStatusId').html(finalGet);

        var UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
        var urlString1 = 'XYZ.php';

        console.log(urlString1);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: urlString1,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            // Your sucsess function 
           }
        });
      });
</script>
```